# DI Singleton instance vs Transient instance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Several years ago IoC performance guidelines stated IoC containers should be used to resolve only long-lived instances (singletons basically), whereas transient type objects should be created using a singleton factory (held by the container).

I am reading now about ASP.NET Core, and several examples I have seen use Transient lifetime for their injected objects.  Has something changed where transient is now the preferred method for services that provide static methods (and are stateless)?

Comment: "Several years ago IoC performance guidelines stated". Do you have a source for this? This is to my knowledge not a common guideline. [The book](https://manning.com/seemann) does certainly not advise this.

Comment: I think mostly people figured out that the performance overhead of constantly creating new service objects isn't that big a deal, compared to the headache of having to ensure that singletons never capture a service with a shorter lifespan. It's easier to start everything out as transient and only diverge from that when there's a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior my experience is actually the other way around. Making complete object graphs singleton has the wonderful benefit of removing lot of common pitfalls like Captive Dependencies, and forces you into a strict stateless model. I have experienced others around me find things being Singleton a much more intuitive model, especially for developers not experienced with DI. It does require stateful objects (like a DbContext) to be stored through ambient state, but still much simpler than finding Captive Dependencies.

Comment: @Steven: It's interesting that you've found singletons reduce the occurrence of captive dependencies. When I've used singleton-by-default in the past, I frequently had captive dependencies because the *dependent* class had to be conscious of the lifespan of its dependencies (a form of tight coupling), whereas transient-by-default means that only classes which need a longer lifespan need to avoid capturing their dependencies. I also find transient scopes force a stateless model whereas singleton scopes tempt developers to maintain state in private fields.

Comment: My findings are the complete opposite. Singletons do not require state in private fields, although it does require Ambient State as part of the Composition Root. My experience is that it is much easier for developers to detect stateful services (which is problematic with singletons), than it is to detect Captive Dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of "long-lived instances" does not say anything about their lifetime or lifestyle per see, but rather that from perspective of the consumer, there is only one instance of them. They are *stateless*.

In other words, "long-lived instances" refers to *services* or *dependencies*, while "short-lived instances" refers to data-centric objects, such as entities, DTOs, messages and view models.

Those services are created and managed by your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (typically, but not nessicarily your DI Container), while data-centric objects are managed directly by application code. In other words, those "long-lived objects" are 'newed' up by the Composition Root, while "short-lived objects" are newed up by application code itself.

Those data-centric objects are volatile, they typically only live for the duration of the request (or even shorter), although they might be cached and live for as long as the application lives.

Dependencies can as well live for a short duration, but typically for the duration of a request.

Comment: I doubt this is what the OP meant by "short-lived instances," since he specifically mentioned that they should be created using a factory, which is not a very common practice for creating DTOs and such.

Comment: You might be right. I was guessing a bit here, since the question does not refer to a source. I'm now thinking that OP is actually referring to the [first edition of Dependency Injection in .NET](https://manning.com/seemann/), which actually describes how factories are a way of working with short-lived dependencies (where the second edition actually now deemphasizes the use of factories). But let's wait for OP to post his sources, so we can place his question in context. I will either update my answer or post a new one based on his sources.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answers!  Unfortunately "IoC performance guidelines" I found somewhere along the way, but I don't recall the exact source. At this point, it's just in my memory.  Interesting point about how factories are being deemphasized.  I will have to read through those passages.  Any pointers on the pages where this is discussed?

Comment: Hi John, [section 6.2 Abuse of Abstract Factories](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-6/section-6-2) of the [second edition](https://manning.com/seemann2/) is devoted to this subject.

Comment: Regarding performance, early dependency injection frameworks could be slow enough to make a significant improvement by using singleton binding (maybe 50 ms per web request, e.g.). I could see people suggesting singleton to get that performance boost. But more modern frameworks like SimpleInjector are much, much faster. SimpleInjector also detects Captive Dependencies at startup, which is super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed.

I am not sure where you read that, but [do note that a service cannot have a lifetime shorter than the services that depend on it](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). So, if you are injecting services into a singleton then you have the right idea - in that case you may need a factory in order to properly release the instance.

However, since ASP.NET Core resolves the controller instance on every request, injecting a transient dependency is fine as it will go out of scope when the controller is destroyed.

Comment: Understood.  I guess I am mostly concerned with performance at this point.  Every transient instance must be created each time it's requested, so I would think that would be detrimental to performance vs. using a Singleton.

Comment: True. But there is nothing stopping you from registering a dependency with a lifetime  *longer* than transient if performance is an issue (i.e. a controller can have a singleton dependency that is shared with other services). Either way, the .NET runtime is optimized to create instances efficiently as long as its [constructor is simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), but at times there are dependencies that are expensive to create that singleton can be beneficial for. Singletons may need to be more complex since they must usually be thread safe.